# Is this the correct pattern to return different views from an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an application that has an public 'end user' mode and a 'back office' mode. Both 'modes' pretty much share the same controller logic but the user interfaces for these different 'modes' are radically different.

Using the out of box default routing that you get when a project is created for the first time I have something like the following:

```
Controllers\
  HomeController.cs

Views
  BackOffice
    Index.aspx
  Public
    Index.aspx

Shared
  BackOfficeSite.Master
  PublicSite.Master
```

In my `HomeController.cs` I have logic that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var devices = DeviceRepository.FindDevicesByCustomer(100);

  if(IsBackOffice()) 
  {
     return View(@"~/Views/BackOffice/Index.aspx", devices);
  }

  return View(@"~/Views/Public/Index.aspx", devices);
}
```

Is this the correct way to be doing this or am I digging myself an anti-pattern hole?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your view folders you can place your BackOffice and Public in your Views/Home folder

```
Views
    Home
      BackOffice
        Index.aspx
      Public
        Index.aspx
```

and your return View should look like this

```
return View("BackOffice/Index", devices);

return View("Public/Index", devices);
```

the controller will always first look for the View inside the View Name folder of the controller. If your Controller is HomeController, it will always look for the View at first in the Views/Home folder.

Comment: Doing `return View(@"~/Views/BackOffice/Index.aspx", devices);` does actually work, even if it isn't the right way to do this. But I think your view folder hierarchy makes much more sense.

Comment: As Kev said, you CAN pass in a relative path to your view in the `View()` function.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I normally don't pass a relative path to my View() function

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if the data that both views need is the same, then it would be ok to use the same controller/route.

However, if they really are that radically different, then each view will likely need it's own set of data in which case, you may be digging yourself into a hole.

You might consider returning the result of another function instead of the view; something like this:

```
return IsBackOffice()? getBackOfficeView() : getPublicView() ;
```

This way you don't have a bunch of if/else in the same controller action.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a view engine to abstract that out. That way all your controller still has to do is:

```
return View(); //or one of the overloads
```